# Public inheritance for all except one function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Car
{
    ...
public:
    void drive(Direction direction);
    void open_door();
    void refuel();
    double get_speed();
    ...
};

class SelfDrivingCar: public Car
{
    CarDrivingProgram *driving_program;
    ...
};

class CarDrivingProgram
{
public:
    virtual void drive_car(Car *car) = 0;
};

class ExampleCarDrivingProgram: public CarDrivingProgram
{
    void drive_car(Car *car) override;
    ...
};
```

SelfDrivingCar is a Car in every way except the user is forbidden from manually driving it. Instead, CarDrivingProgram drives it via drive_car(...). Using public inheritance seems correct because most operations on a Car could also happen to a SelfDrivingCar. For example, the user might create an array of Cars and then refuel all the Cars in the array, some of which happen to be SelfDrivingCars.

However, using public inheritance exposes the drive(...) method, which the user should not call on a SelfDrivingCar.

One solution would be to make the drive(...) method private in SelfDrivingCar, but that's messy, requires all CarDrivingPrograms to be friends in order to access drive(...), and can be circumvented if the user casts a SelfDrivingCar to a Car and then calls drive(...) from the Car.

Another solution would be to keep a boolean flag that indicates whether a Car is currently allowed to be driven or not and printing an error if drive(...) is called when the flag is set to "false". For a SelfDrivingCar, this flag would be "false" for most of the time, and CarDrivingProgram would temporarily set this to "true" for the duration of drive_car(...). However, this catches mistakes at runtime rather than at compile time, and the user can still toggle the flag and drive a SelfDrivingCar manually if they really want to.

Using protected/private inheritance would be another solution, but that prevents the user from doing something like adding SelfDrivingCars to an array of Cars that are to be later refuelled (described earlier).

How do I cleanly forbid the user from calling drive() on a SelfDrivingCar, ideally catching things at compile thing?

For clarification: The SelfDrivingCar class still needs a drive(...) function or something like it because CarDrivingProgram needs a way to tell SelfDrivingCar the direction to drive in. CarDrivingPrograms can drive any Car, not just SelfDrivingCars. I want CarDrivingProgram to be able to drive SelfDrivingCars but for the user to be unable to. For example, the user could have an array of pairs of CarDrivingPrograms and Cars, and call carDrivingProgram[i]->drive_car(car[i]) for each pair. I could make all CarDrivingPrograms friends but that's messy.

Comment: In your design, it seems that being able to `drive` is not a fundamental part of being a `Car`. In that case, you could factor out `drive` into a separate class that only `drive`able classes inherit from.

Comment: "How do I cleanly forbid the user from calling drive()" you don't. `SelfDrivingCar` is a `Car` and a `Car` can `drive()` it's that simple. Furthermore, imagine if code had a `Car*` pointer to a `SelfDrivingCar` - then they could call `drive()`. If your class hierarchy doesn't properly model the situation you need to represent, then you need to refactor your classes.

Comment: To reiterate -- this cannot be done at compile time. C++ does not work this way. At compile time, it cannot be determine whether a pointer to a Car is really a pointer to SelfDrivingCar. It can be a pointer to any Car, and it is logically impossible, in C++, to determine that.

Comment: Maybe instead of having a `SelfDrivingCar`, have a separate hierarchy of `Driver` classes that tell a `Car` what to do (accelerate, brake, steer, etc), and then you can have `HumanDriver` and `SelfDriver` classes to make those kind of decisions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Car { 
    ... 
    public: 
    void open_door(); 
    void refuel(); 
    double get_speed(); 
    ... 
}; 
class NormalCar: public Car{
    public:
    void drive(Direction direction);
};
class SelfDrivingCar: public Car
{ 
    CarDrivingProgram *driving_program; 
... 
};
```

This is a very clean way. When there are no reasons you can't introduce another class, this should be fine. You can still store them in an array and refuel them.

When SelfDrivingCar is a Car that can drive, you can make it a Car and call the function (like TheUndeadFish mentioned in his comment). But you can't make a SelfDrivingCar a NormalCar.